# Timer and AlarmManager in foreground Service in android 8

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

I want get location periodically and send to server. I wrote this with AlarmManager and works well in below version 6 and some devices with above version 6. but in Samsung devices is not work and call in on time. I searched and i found, i should to use Foreground Service. in Foreground service Alarm Manager and Timer is run specific Time? Or in doze mode is not reliable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not gonna do something that should be noticed by the user than you should use JobScheduler for your scheduled jobs instead of using background service or foreground service. After the Android Oreo there are some more limitations for the background jobs. You can check out the limitations and how you should implement from [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) .

Comment: I want get Location periodically and i want use foreground service. Can i use AlarmManager and Timer for working in doze mode in foreground services?

Comment: If you will use foreground service, yes you can use alarmmanager and timer.

Comment: I used, but not run in exact time :( Please help me

Comment: How precise do you want that ?

Comment: I use timer and alarmManager for get location and send to server periodically. but in doze mode, my device not work good. I used foreground service.